# List child terms and posts in the current term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, sidebar, hierarchical, sub-menu

With this code parent term page lists all the child terms and the child term page lists all of the posts in current term, and the single page lists a big flat list of terms(hierarchical).

Now,

The parent term page is fine.

When it's child term page, i want to list all child terms( not showing with this code ) + the posts in current term( showing ).

And when it's single post, i want to list the same as child term page.

```
        $term = get_queried_object();
        $tax = 'ntp_package_type';
        $parents = $term->parent;
        $term_id = $term->term_id;

        if($parents == 0){
            wp_list_categories( array (
                            'taxonomy'  => 'ntp_package_type',
                            'pad_counts'=> 0,
                            'title_li'  => '',
                            'child_of'  => $term_id,
                            )
            );
        }
        elseif (is_tax($tax, $term->name)){

            $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'ntp_package',
                    $tax => $term->name,
            );
            $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
            if( $wp_query->have_posts() ):
            while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
            echo "<p><a href=\"".get_permalink()."\">".$post->post_title."</a></p>";
            endwhile;
            endif;

        }
        elseif (is_single()){

        }
```

It is for a sidebar sub nav.  is it a right way to do?
I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i don't know how this looks but i've got exactly what i wanted.

```
<?php
        $term = get_queried_object();
        $tax = 'ntp_package_type';
        $parents = $term->parent;
        $term_id = $term->term_id;

        if($parents == 0 && !is_single()){
        wp_list_categories( array (
                            'taxonomy'  => 'ntp_package_type',
                            'pad_counts'=> 0,
                            'title_li'  => '',
                            'child_of'  => $term_id,
                            )
            );  
        }

        elseif ($parents > 0 && is_tax($tax, $tax->name)){

            $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'ntp_package',
                    $tax => $term->name,
            );
            echo "<h2>".$term->name."</h2>";

            $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
            if( $wp_query->have_posts() ):
            while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); 

            echo "<p><a href=\"".get_permalink()."\">".$post->post_title."</a></p>";
            endwhile;
            endif;
            wp_reset_postdata();

            wp_list_categories( array (
                'taxonomy'  => 'ntp_package_type',
                'pad_counts'=> 0,
                'title_li'  => '',
                'child_of'  => $term->parent,
                'exclude'   => $term_id,
                )
            );
        }

        elseif(is_single()){

        $single = get_queried_object();
        $sing_id = $single->ID;

        $singterm = wp_get_post_terms($sing_id, $tax);
        $singterm_slug = $singterm[0]->slug;
        $singterm_parent = $singterm[0]->parent;
        $singterm_id = $singterm[0]->term_id;

        $args = array(
                'taxonomy'  => $tax,
                'term'      => $singterm_slug,
        );
        ?>

        <h2>
        <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($singterm_slug, $tax); ?>"><?php echo $singterm[0]->name; ?> </a>
        </h2>

        <?php
        $singquery = new WP_Query($args);
        while ($singquery->have_posts()) : $singquery->the_post();
        ?>

        <p>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </p>

        <?php
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();


        wp_list_categories( array (
            'taxonomy'  => 'ntp_package_type',
            'pad_counts'=> 0,
            'title_li'  => '',
            'child_of'  => $singterm_parent,
            'exclude'   => $singterm_id,
            )
        );  

        }


        ?>
```